# Static background noise while using new headset

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

Today I bought a new gaming headset (Gx-Gaming Lychas), and when I tried to record some gameplay-comentary I noticed that there always is a static background noise, I just recorded an example so you guys can listen it (no downloaded needed):

http://www47.zippyshare.com/v/65167832/file.html

I'm using Kubuntu 13.04 and Kernel version is 3.8.0-19, my laptop is an Acer Travelmate 5760Z, I tried tons of configurations on Alsamixer and none of them made result, I really need to get this working so any kind of help will be very aprecciated.

**cat /proc/asound/cards:**

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xc6400000 irq 44
```

**cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0**

```
Codec: Conexant CX20588
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x14f1506c
Subsystem Id: 0x10250574
Revision Id: 0x100003
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=4, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[3]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20588 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=8, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x12 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x13 [Beep Generator Widget] wcaps 0x70000c: Mono Amp-Out
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x07, nsteps=0x07, stepsize=0x0f, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00]
Node 0x14 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20588 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x50 0x50] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=4, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17* 0x18 0x23 0x24
Node 0x15 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17* 0x18 0x23 0x24
Node 0x16 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x17* 0x18 0x23 0x24
Node 0x17 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x04 0x04]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x1a 0x1b* 0x1d 0x1e
Node 0x18 [Audio Selector] wcaps 0x30050d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 4
     0x1a* 0x1b 0x1d 0x1e
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Headphone Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x0000001c: OUT HP Detect
  Pin Default 0x04214040: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400481: Stereo
  Control: name="Internal Mic Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00001324: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  Pin Default 0x90a70130: [Fixed] Mic at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Control: name="Mic Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00011334: IN OUT EAPD Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 80
  EAPD 0x0:
  Pin Default 0x04a19020: [Jack] Mic at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Pink
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000014: OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00010034: IN OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x0:
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400481: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000024: IN Detect
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1f [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400501: Stereo
  Control: name="Speaker Phantom Jack", index=0, device=0
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x92170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int Front
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11*
Node 0x20 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x12
Node 0x21 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x611: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x22 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400781: Stereo Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x21
Node 0x23 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40040b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x04, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x24 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20050b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11
Node 0x25 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
```

Comment: If you can record the background noise in the software, then it's likely that your microphone is turned on for the "play" mixer. Have you tried opening `alsamixer` (terminal) and mute the microphone? (press M on the right slider)

Comment: Do you have the same "hum"-noise when running on battery ?

Comment: @thom I don't have this "hum" noise when I unplug the power cable, what shall I do next? I tried the solution here but no luck none of this work until now . any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

You have to modify the following line in

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Change

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

to:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

You can refer to this link :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/751265/comments/23

Comment: tried this but I still have the same problem with Lenovo t440p with 14.10, but I had this issues from the 12.04. with windows 8 is fine no noise

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with lots of noise that would vary with scrolling and other activities. I opened alsamixer and turned down "Beep", and the noise went away.

Comment: can confirm, this still works

Answer (score 1):

A recent update to the pulseaudio package included with Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) and Kubuntu 13.04 may be causing some users to experience a persistent background noise, or hum. It appears that this particular bug will affect VLC, Skype, and possibly other applications which emit audio. This problem is primarily affecting Intel-HDA (high definition audio) chipsets and ALSA sound drivers in regards to "glitch-free" PA (pulse audio).

Source: [Ubuntu Linux Knowhow](http://ubuntulinuxknowhow.blogspot.com/2013/06/static-background-noise-ubuntu-1304.html)

**[bug 751265](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/751265/comments/23)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that that static is coming from your motherboard. Try using USB headphones so that you don't get interference from the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was going on the alsamixer and put the headeset mic up to 22