# thinkpad t440p annoying static noise when I plug the speakers realtek ALC292 HDA Intel PCH 13.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, noise, hda-intel

some laptop thinkpad t440p , with windows 8 is fine no noise.

with ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 , if I plug the speakers without music but with the volume up(even low) there is annoying noise come out.

to interrupt the noise I need to put in mute mode.

```
aplay -l
*** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC292 Analog [ALC292 Analog]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


dpkg -l | grep alsa
 ii  alsa-base                                 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4                          all          ALSA driver configuration files
 ii  alsa-utils                                1.0.27.1-1ubuntu1                             amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
 ii  bluez-alsa:amd64                          4.101-0ubuntu8b1                              amd64        Bluetooth ALSA support
 ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64                  0.10.36-1.1ubuntu1                            amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
 ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                   1.2.0-1ubuntu1                                amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA


dpkg -l | grep pulseaudio
ii  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64            0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu3                         amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64             1.2.0-1ubuntu1                                amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  pulseaudio                                1:4.0-0ubuntu6                                amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth               1:4.0-0ubuntu6                                amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-x11                     1:4.0-0ubuntu6                                amd64        X11 module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                          1:4.0-0ubuntu6                                amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server

 uname -a
3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


alsamixer
 Card: HDA Intel PCH                                                                                                                            F1:  Help               │
 Chip: Realtek ALC292
```

Comment: I have tried with ppa 
     "ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily"
 and install  "oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms" 
but still the issues .

Comment: discovered that only the right earphone make the noise , on the left is ok

Comment: I hear the same thing, though I get it through both channels, left and right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static background noise while using new headset Ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/292786/static-background-noise-while-using-new-headset-ubuntu-13-04)

Comment: I don't have this "hum" noise sometime when I unplug the power cable.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Fixed follow this:
http://xps13-9333.appspot.com/#background_noise

with

    `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
    wget -O /usr/local/bin/white_noise_fix.py http://xps13-9333.appspot.com/root/usr/local/bin/white_noise_fix.py
    chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/white_noise_fix.py`

changed the script on /etc/init.d/xps this line:

`kernel_version=$(uname -r | cut -c3-4)`

to

`kernel_version=$(uname -r | cut -c3)`